# Web app to control a device

Tags: python, web-services, user-interface, graphics, frontend

This is very very general question. I need to develop a web app to control a small system and I'd like to have a web browser gui instead of creating an application.
This web app needs to have a graphical part representing the status of the system that I want to control.
My problem is to develop quickly for instyance with a framework like web2py or similar. In this way I can create text field, table and many things usually found in a web site and that is good.
The only doubt is related to the way I can add an dynamic image (synoptic) representing the status (for example a tank with the level inside changing).

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: You can use one of the many mobile-friendly JS widget toolkits.

Comment: To be simple, you can refresh the status every time the web gets refreshed.